# How to play audio file located on server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am working on a website to be used in local network. I displayed audio files that are stored on server in a GridView. Now I want that file to be played by user on client PC when user selects one from gridview. Is there any plugin available or if I can just simply play the file using Play or Pause Buttons Corresponding to that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link. It may helps you out

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-MP3-Audio-Files-to-database-and-display-in-ASPNet-GridView-with-Play-and-Download-option.aspx

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvAudioPlayer" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="File Name" HeaderText="FileName" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Play">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data='dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=<%#Eval("mp3file") %>'
                            width="240" height="20" id="dewplayer">
                            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                            <param name="movie" value="dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=<%#Eval("mp3file") %>" />
                        </object>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

In code behind

```
DataTable dtFiles = new DataTable();
    dtFiles.Columns.Add("File Name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dtFiles.Columns.Add("mp3file", Type.GetType("System.String"));

    string filepath = Server.MapPath("mp3");//folder name which contains audio files
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

    foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.mp3"))
    {
        dtFiles.Rows.Add(file.FullName, string.Format(@"mp3/{0}", file.Name));
    }
    gvAudioPlayer.DataSource=dtFiles;
    gvAudioPlayer.DataBind();
```

and then download and keep the Dewplayer (http://www.alsacreations.fr/dl/dewplayer.zip) in the root of your application.

Comment: Is it necessary that Songs folder should reside in website folder?
Because i tried to use a folder that is in different Local Drive. And it stops working