# Inserting and retrieving audio files from MySQL using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I saved an audio file in a MySQL database successfully but I don't know how to retrieve and play it from the database. Any help will be appreciated.

This is my code for insertion:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        MySqlConnection connection;
        string cs = @"server = 127.0.0.1; userid = root; pwd = ; database = atlfmdb;";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);

        if (upload.Text.Length > 0 && 
            vName.Text.Length > 0 && 
            vTel.Text.Length>0 && 
            tbposition.Text.Length>0)
        {
            string FileName = upload.Text;

            byte[] f = File.ReadAllBytes(upload.Text) ;

            MySqlCommand selectcom = new MySqlCommand("insert into interinterview(intName,intPosition,intTel,audioFile)values('" + vName.Text + "','" +  tbposition.Text + "','" + vTel.Text + "','" + f + "')", connection);
            MySqlDataReader myread;

            connection.Open();
            myread = selectcom.ExecuteReader();
            while (myread.Read())
            {
            }

            connection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved successfully");
            vName.Text = "";
            vTel.Text = "";
            tbposition.Text = "";
            upload.Text = "";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Audio files | *.mp3";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            upload.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You saved this values to your database but you can't read them from database? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And use `using` statement to dispose your database connections and objects

Comment: i can retrieve the rest of the data but not the audio files.

Comment: i tried to play the audio files using media player but it says the files have .datarowview extension

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not worked out the solution, I've just worked it out based on the answer in this link:
[How to play audio file located on server in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557930/how-to-play-audio-file-located-on-server-in-asp-net)

At the end of this link it gives you the location of Dewplayer zip package. Download and put the dewplayer-vol.swf file into your root folder.

You need to convert all the MS SQL commands to MySQL and put the MySQL.DLL into your bin folder as well if not there. In my case, I store the mp3 files as varbinay and retrieve it using a stored procedure something like this:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
  string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlServer"].ConnectionString;

   using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {

        using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("getaudio", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            using (IDataReader idr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = idr;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            conn.Close();               
        }
     }
}
```

More details in this link:
http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-MP3-Audio-Files-to-database-and-display-in-ASPNet-GridView-with-Play-and-Download-option.aspx

You need to create a file say Audio.ashx and put it into the root folder. Hope this can help you.